# Is there a way to set the source of the image to font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I have a div, which will have a dummy image by defualt. I am setting the src to a camera picture when there is a click on the div. Till now that dummy image used to be an URL. But now I was suggested to use font-awesome. Is there any way that I can set `src1 of the image tag to font-awesome icon.

Here is the image tag

```
<img className="cam" src={this.state.image1} onClick={this.camera} data-cam={1}/>
```

Comment: yeah just set the `className` to `null` and after the click set it to your icon class, e.g. `fa fa-chrome`

Comment: I suppose you can set a `background-image` but you also have to set a `height` and `width`. Not sure if you gain anything with it though.

Comment: Why my code was not shown in colors, before you edited? @James

Comment: @gates because you'd wrapped it in inline code tags `\`code\`` whereas I've indented it with 4 spaces `    code`.

Comment: that would work fine for i tag, not image @knowbody

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Font Awesome does not use images for icons and an `img` element without a `src` attribute is invalid HTML.

What you can do instead is add logic to show or hide the dummy icon beside the image. Here is an example using a `class` on a parent wrapper:

```
<div className="show-icon">
    <i className="fa fa-..."></i>
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

When the parent `div` element has a class of `.show-icon`, you can use CSS to show the icon and hide the image:

```css
div i.fa { display: none; }
div img { display: block; }

div.show-icon i.fa { display: inline-block; }
div.show-icon img { display: none; }
```